# Can we submit a jsp form twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, jsp

I have one submit button, on click of which normal submission of a form should work.
I have another element, a check box on click of which I need to submit the form.
Is it possible?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**:

```
var checkbox = document.yourForm.yourCheckbox; // getting yourCheckbox
checkbox.onclick = function() {                // a function that is executed when the checkbox is clicked
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {            // if checkbox is checked:
        document.yourForm.submit();            // submit the form
    }
};
```

**HTML**:

```
<form name="yourForm">
    <input type='checkbox' name='yourCheckbox'>
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Thanks for this help  !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='handleClick(this);'>Checkbox

function handleClick(cb) {
if(cb.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you confirm on whether the separate submit button for the same form would have no issues submitting the form ?

Comment: Yes, no issues in that